# How to find an object using phone number as key to search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hi this is one of my objects in the database and now i need to find the objects based on the phone no. How can i do this with mongoose and nodejs?? please help me out

```
    Father :{
      Firstname:{
                type:String,
                required:true
              },
      Lastname:{
                type:String,
                required:true
                },
      Occupation:{
                  type:String,
                  required:true
                },
      PlaceOfWork:{
                   type:String,
                   required:true
                  },
      OfficialAddress:{
                      type:String,
                      required:true
                    },
      EmailId:{
                type:String,
                required:true
              },
      PhoneNo:{
                type:Number,
                required:true
              }};
```

Comment: `Model.find(query, fields, options, callback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily find the data with phoneNo.

```
databaseName.find({Father.PhoneNo: req.body.PhoneNo}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({status: 0, message: err});
                }
                if (!user) {
                    res.json({status: 0, msg: "not found"});
                }
                res.json({status: 1, id: user._id, message: " success"});
            })
```

Comment: thanks for accepted for my answer, you can also upvote